# Is it possible to get programmatic access to finder preview images?

Tags: image, macos, finder

Finder makes these great preview images of files.  Is it possible to access them? Ideally from python.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://mattgemmell.com/files/source/nsimage_quicklook.zip it does exactly what you want event if it is in obj-c

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the command like using `qlmanage` discussed here:

[API or other method for accessing Finder icon preview images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007775/api-or-other-method-for-accessing-finder-icon-preview-images)