# API or other method for accessing Finder icon preview images

Tags: bash, macos

It appears that macOS now generates preview images for certain files (notably RAW image files) that are not custom icons but something else. (You can toggle them on/off in latish model macOS via "show icon preview" in Finder window "Show View Options".)

I'd love to be able to either obtain these images or use the API that generates them but I'm obviously googling the wrong terms. The usual APIs will get me the file icon (which is usually a generic document icon) and not the preview. The tricks for getting custom icons (e.g. .DS_Store etc.) do not apply.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think the tag changes are correct since the QuickLook framework is accessible via Swift / Obj-C.

Comment: But your question has nothing to do with either language. The answer you accepted make no use of either language.

Comment: But I would love to have received a detailed answer showing, for example, how to use the [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook) framework using either language, and someone who codes in said languages won't see the question because of your edit. Similarly, someone who codes in Swift of Obj-C who wants to know which framework is involved won't find the answer as easily.

Comment: I'm also guessing that @rob-napier wouldn't have seen my question without the tags it had on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool you want is `qlmanage`. In particular, look at `qlmanage -t` (thumbnail) and `qlmanage -p` (preview). By default, it opens a viewer for you. If you want to generate files to process yourself, see the `-o` option. For example:

```
qlmanage -t image.png -o .
```

This will create a thumbnail file called `./image.png.png` (it attaches `.png` to whatever the filename is).

If you want to build your own tools around this, see the [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook#) framework.

Comment: Thank you. I'd looked at qlmanage but hadn't figured out how to get it to generate output.

Answer (score 1):

A little more info w.r.t. using [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook) framework. The key method is [QLThumbnailImageCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/1402623-qlthumbnailimagecreate) (QuickLook previews are PDFs which are not what I want and likely not what someone doing something similar wants).

Even though the function name indicates that it creates thumbnails, it can create an image of any size (and the size parameter dictates a maximum dimension).